# Dynamics CRM 4.0 hangs because of deadlocks

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have Microsoft Dynamic CRM 4.0 and we are facing lots of long query executions.
Mostly CRM hangs on specific views and wait for 4-5 minutes.

We have found deadlocks on SQL Server and I guess it's because CRM doesn't use with(nolock) statement on select queries.

Is it possible to change queries and add with(nolock) statements for views on CRM?
Is there anything that you suggest us?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Use SQL query analysis tools to help determine fields that could benefit from a new (or revised) index.
- The QueryExpression class has a NoLock property that you can set where appropriate.
- Make sure all views in CRM are useful. For example, if the default view for Account is to bring back all active accounts but no one every needs to see all accounts then change the default view to only show what's useful for end-users. That might mean they don't need to see any records by default; they might always want to search or choose their own default view. Doing this type of analysis will help reduce the work that SQL needs to do.
- Determine whether there's old data that you can archive out of CRM to improve performance.